# Getting Zend Framework 2 Memcached working

Tags: php, memcached, zend-framework2, zend-cache

I'm trying to create a new (configured and ready to use) `Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Memcached` and getting a error:

> File: [project]/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Cache/Storage/Adapter/MemcachedResourceManager.php:52
>   Message: No resource with id 'default'

`Module` class

```
class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface, ServiceProviderInterface, AutoloaderProviderInterface {
    ...
    public function getServiceConfig() {
        try {
            return array (
                'factories' => array(
                    ...
                    'Cache\Adapter\Memcached' => function ($serviceManager) {
                        $memcached = new Memcached($serviceManager->get('Cache\Adapter\MemcachedOptions'));
                        return $memcached;
                    },
                    'Cache\Adapter\MemcachedOptions' => function ($serviceManager) {
                        return new MemcachedOptions(array(
                            'ttl'           => 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 1 week
                            'namespace'     => 'cache_listener',
                            'key_pattern'   => null,
                            'readable'      => true,
                            'writable'      => true,
                            'servers'       => 'localhost',
                        ));
                    },
                    'Search\Model\CityStorage' => function ($serviceManager) {
                        return new CityStorage(
                            $serviceManager->get('Search\Model\CityTable'),
                            $serviceManager->get('Cache\Adapter\Memcached')
                        );
                    }
                )
            );
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

`Controller` class

```
class SearchController extends AbstractActionController {
    ...
    public function searchCoursesAction() {
        ...
        return new ViewModel(array(
            ...
            'cities' => $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Search\Model\CityStorage')->getCities(),
        ));
    }
    ...
}
```

`Storage` class

```
<?php
namespace Search\Model;

use Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\AbstractAdapter;
use Search\Model\CityTable;

class CityStorage {

    /**
     * @var CityTable
     */
    private $cityTable;
    /**
     * @var AbstractAdapter
     */
    private $cacheAdapter;

    public function __construct(CityTable $cityTable, AbstractAdapter $cacheAdapter) {
        $this->cityTable    = $cityTable;
        $this->cacheAdapter = $cacheAdapter;
        $this->cacheCities();
    }

    public function getCities() {
        if (!$this->cacheAdapter->hasItem('cities')) {
            $this->cacheCities();
        }
        return $cacheAdapter->getItem('cities');
    }

    private function cacheCities() {
        // $cities = $this->cityTable->fetchAll()->toArray();
        // $this->cacheAdapter->setItem('cities', $cities);
        $this->cacheAdapter->setItem('test', 123);
    }

}
```

How to get it working?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

I've completed the `MemcachedOptions` with the setting `servers` (see above). Now it works!

Note: `servers` and not `server`, since there is no method `setServer()`, but only `setServers()` in the `Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\MemcachedOptions` class:

> File: /var/www/itt/unisportr-zf/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Stdlib/AbstractOptions.php:85
>   Message: The option "server" does not have a matching setServer setter method which must be defined

Answer (score 0):

As you already noted, you have to define a resource - means a basic `\Memcached` instance or one of the options auto-instantiate a resource. (Please take a look into `Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\MemcachedResource`)
... The reason for this is to share one or more `\Memcached` resources over different storage adapter instances.

Please also note that the `AbstractAdapter` isn't the marker for type hints - you should type hint by the StorageInterface ;)